# Очевидные самоответы - нужно ли?

Tags: обсуждение

Начало было положено вопросом про типы данных в Perl. Давно было, ссылку не помню. И тут фигакс: [Нижнее подчёркивание и -s, что обозначают?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804160/)
Я понимаю стремление подняться в рейтинге (как юзера, так и сайта), но не такими же топорными методами.
Давайте ещё весь `man` сюда импортируем.

P.S. Свой ответ удаляю, ибо нефиг.

Comment: Но там нет самоответа

Comment: Я в августе специально покопировал несколько элементарных моментов из мана по питону, но вопросы и ответы до сих пор на месте, а один даже заплюсован ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @FoggyFinder, если посмотреть на [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/804160/revisions), то можно увидеть, что автор дополнил свой вопрос, добавив в него ответ - что, в общем-то не очень хорошо, т.к. следует вынести решение отдельно.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский если посмотреть на время последней правки и сравнить с временем публикации вопроса на мете, то можно увидеть, что автор дополнил свой вопрос, добавив в него ответ (ответ ли?) уже после открытия обсуждения

Answer (score 10):

Для кого самоочевидные, для кого-то нет.

У меня есть коллеги, которые очень многие сложные вещи считают очевидными.

Кстати, приведённый вами пример вопроса: я лично не только не знаю, что там за ответ (но я правда не занимался перлом, разве что очень давно и эпизодически) но мало того - ещё и не уверен, что поисковики поймут знаки подчеркивания, доллара (в c# есть подобные вопросы - а гуглит надо string interpolation) и прочие спецзнаки.

Подобные темы кстати не так и просто найти даже поиском по stackoverflow, надо думать как составить поисковый запрос.

Поэтому я сам подобные темы создавать вряд ли стал, но чинить искусственные препятствия смысла не вижу.

Answer (score 5):

"Самоответы" - отличный способ поделиться с сообществом своим опытом в той или иной области. Например, [Дмитрий Полянин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/205037) таким образом рассказывает об очень интересных решениях на [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) и [svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg).

Конечно, встречаются и такие "самоответы", ценность которых для сообщества сомнительна. Безусловно, любой вправе голосовать против таких вопросов, но смотреть на них стоит объективно и в первую очередь оценивать то, какую пользу для сообщества и его потенциальных членов они несут.